# pytest: prevent imported auto-used session fixture from executing multiple times

Tags: python, testing, pytest, fixtures

My pytest test files are spread across multiple packages, and they share some common fixtures. However, I found that my auto-used session-scoped fixture is ran multiple times.

Here is a basic structure of my project:

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── __init__.py
├── common
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── conftest.py
├── pkg_a
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   └── test_a.py
└── pkg_b
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── conftest.py
    └── test_b.py
```

And here are the content of each `.py` file:

```
==> ./__init__.py <==

==> ./common/__init__.py <==

==> ./common/conftest.py <==
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def setup():
    print 'setting up'
    yield
    print 'tearing down'


==> ./pkg_a/__init__.py <==

==> ./pkg_a/conftest.py <==
from common.conftest import *

==> ./pkg_a/test_a.py <==
def test():
    assert True

==> ./pkg_b/__init__.py <==

==> ./pkg_b/conftest.py <==
from common.conftest import *

==> ./pkg_b/test_b.py <==
def test_b():
    assert True
```

Here is the output of pytest:

```
➜ pytest -s pkg_a pkg_b
========================== test session starts ==========================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.15, pytest-3.10.0, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: /path/to/the/project, inifile:
collected 2 items

pkg_a/test_a.py setting up
.
pkg_b/test_b.py setting up
.tearing down
tearing down


======================= 2 passed in 0.02 seconds ========================
```

My understanding to the session fixtures is that they will only be ran once for the lifetime of `pytest` command. But here the `setting up` and `tearing down` are printed twice, and they are interleaved.

Is there any way to only execute the fixture only once? I want the `setting up` to be printed only once at the beginning and `tearing down` at the very end for the whole test session.

P.S. I know the parameterized session fixture will be execute multiple times. But I don't think my fixture is parameterized.

Comment: the project structure looks a bit misconfigured (why do you have an `__init__.py` in the project root dir? is it a package? why are test directories made to packages?). Also, importing from `conftest`s is a bad practice as it can easily break things; `conftest`s are not meant to be regular python modules, they will be automatically executed by `pytest` when found. Suggestion: remove unnecessary `__init__.py`s, remove `conftest` imports, move `common/conftest.py` to the project root dir.

Comment: @hoefling understood. thanks for your suggestion! Yes, the current structure of my project is a bit messy. I'm still wondering... is it possible to archive the fixture under current structure?

Comment: @hoefling I think it makes sense to have the test file siting side by side with the logic code. I removed the `__init__.py` in the root folder, but the result is the same.

Comment: Again: you have to introduce a `conftest.py` in the project root dir where the tests are executed and remove the conftest imports.

Comment: You can keep the tests along with the production code, but you have to be far more careful about organizing the code. `pytest` will append parent dirs of `conftest` files to `sys.path`, which can easily introduce import issues - especially when you're keeping tests in python packages.  It makes sense to take a look at [Good Integration Practices](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#good-integration-practices), however from my experience keeping tests in source dir only makes sense when you are going to release tests with the source code, like `numpy` or `pandas` do.

Comment: @hoefling thanks a lot for your explanation! So I think I need to refactor my layout and there won't be such problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Session scoped fixture is supposed to run only once. But if you look closely, there are two setup fixtures for test_a. One from common/conftest.py and other from pkg_a/conftest.py. You don't need to import common.conftest.py in pkg_a/conftest.py. pytest starts collecting conftest files starting from project root. 
You can see the fixture setup process with `--setup-show` switch: `pytest test_a.py --setup-show`.

To solve your problem, you can remove `from common.conftest import *` from your test_a(b)/conftest.py files .

More about conftest collection of pytest here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/plugins.html

Comment: If I remove the `import` from `pkg_a/conftest.py`, the fixture is not executed for the `pkg_a`. If I remove the `import` from both package, the fixture is not executed at all. No `setting up` and `tearing down` is printed. What I want is the `setting up` appears at the very beginning and `tearing down` at the very end only once.